# Reading Travis build notifications with Python

Tags: python, travis-ci

I've built a Python script that gets all scans all of our Jira boards each morning to see if there were any releases the previous day, then posts that information to a Google sheet. There's one project that doesn't currently list their releases in Jira, its a big team that runs a lot of releases each week, even each day. They use Github and Travis CI and I was wondering if there's a way I can expose the Travis build notifications to my Python script - I really just need the release date, version, and release name.